# How do display Day Name instead of Createddate in Salefsorce Report Chart?

Tags: salesforce

I want to display day name instead of date in salesforce standard report chart.

i.e :
09/01/2018 should display as Tuesday.

[instead of Date i want day name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7HJN.jpg)

Comment: When there are two dates of same day, won't it display two `Tuesday`s? Or, are you trying to group by days?

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment on your post, I am giving my thoughts here as an answer.

Since you can't directly show this in reports, you may have to create a formula field in your object which will display the Day from the date field. You can use the below formula for the same.

```
CASE ( MOD(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7), 0, "Sunday", 1, "Monday", 2, "Tuesday", 3, 
"Wednesday", 4, "Thursday", 5, "Friday", 6, "Saturday","Error")
```

Once created you can show the same in reports. Remember to group by using this field so that you can use the field on charts.

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Man Thats My final thought also !!

Comment: Welcome @ParthNaik

Comment: I shyam i got day of week from the formula thanks for that but how do i used this field as X-Axis of chart i.e i want to display day of the week instead of createddate on chart X-Axis